# Smart slicer to filter out already selected value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am looking for a way to build smart Slicer [Slice_2] that options out already selected option in Slicer [Slicer_1]. For instance if proj_short_name = NBA-UC-02 is selected on Slicer 1, Slicer 2 should display rest all except NBA-UC-02 as shown below.

[image]

Excel attached for quick reference: [excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CnlyYqIf5IVXAh9FdYg3P9RaZDXPdxlF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111637703513802384395&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Hardly believe that this can be possible even in theory. The purpose of a slicer - filtering, so, If you have 2 slicers that contradicts each other nothing will be filtered. It's better to find an other idea for a  data manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input @Mik. Not sure how to close this question.

Comment: You are welcome ). It's not necessary to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @Mik said in a comment:

Hardly believe that this can be possible even in theory. The purpose of a slicer - filtering, so, If you have 2 slicers that contradicts each other nothing will be filtered. It's better to find an other idea for a data manipulation.